# I am trying to make a product which will reformat the answer using the question and Sql_answer as data

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, nlp-question-answering, h2o.ai

Question:"How many employees are there in Department X"

Sql_answer:[('2'),]

I want the model generate the answer in this format:

Expected answer:"There are 2 employees in Department X."

On using the web client h2oai gpt(h2oai/h2ogpt-4096-llama2-13b-chat) I am getting the correct response however the same prompt is not working with the downloaded transformers (h2oai/h2ogpt-4096-llama2-13b-chat) for the same model. It worked for first 3-4 times then it started generating random text generation.

I tried using t5, gpt2 but I was not getting the expected answer.

Can someone suggest a method or model for this?